# How to set initial value of input field when using vm as controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using john papa style to develop my angular app so there is controller passing data to another controller using service. In second controller, I want to set the input field value when controller get call. I tried to set it like

> vm.form.mobile = getMob[1].mobile;

but this did not work for me.

**Here is my second controller**

```
 (function ()
    {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app.pages.auth.verify-mobile')
            .controller('VerifyMobileController', VerifyMobileController);

        /** @ngInject */
        function VerifyMobileController($scope,dataservice,msApi, $state,$mdDialog)
        {
            var vm = this;
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                $state.go('app.pages_auth_login');
            }
            var getMob = dataservice.getData();
            if(typeof getMob !== 'undefined'){

               vm.form.mobile = getMob[1].mobile;

            }
}
}();
```

**Here is html element**

```
<form name="verifyMobileForm" novalidate>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float>
                    <input type="mobile" id="mobile" name="mobile" ng-model="vm.form.mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile number" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10" required>
                    <div ng-messages="verifyMobileForm.mobile.$error" role="alert" multiple>
                        <div ng-message="required">
                            <span >Mobile no. is required</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </md-input-container>
                <div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-margin layout-align="center">
                    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-accent submit-button" ng-disabled="verifyMobileForm.$invalid || verifyMobileForm.$pristine" ng-click = "vm.checkMobile($event, document.getElementById('mobile').value)">
                        Next
                    </md-button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle this way it is easier to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add ng-value attribute
ng-value="{{vm.form.mobile}}"

for example:

```
<input type="mobile" id="mobile" name="mobile" ng-value="{{vm.form.mobile}}" ng-model="vm.form.mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile number" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10" required>
```

Comment: I got this error in console "angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined"

Comment: maybe try change in JS:
     var getMob = dataservice.getData();
     vm.form = {};
     vm.form.mobile = getMob[1].mobile;

and also add ng-value attribute

Comment: Thank you so much @kanion. you are great.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using controllerAs syntax in your view, as such:

```
<div ng-controller="VerifyMobileController as vm">
```

Edit: By the way

```
 if(typeof getMob !== 'undefined')
```

Might one day shoot you in the foot when the result comes back as null or NaN, a more common way to write this is just:

```
if(getMob)
```

Comment: I am using the correct controller.because rest of the code is working correctly, only I want to set the value of input field when the controller get call.

Comment: Make sure you define vm.form first, before assigning vm.form.mobile.
Or like this: vm.form = {mobile : getMob[1].mobile;}

Comment: Nope. still has some problem.